# bamboo server on ec2 instance, how to secure the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, bamboo

I loaded Bamboo server onto and AWS Ec2 instance but it is not secure. When I try to link Bamboo to Bitbucket I get a Failed to load data from Bitbucket. [403 Forbidden].
So after reading [this](https://medium.com/devoops-and-universe/ci-cd-workflow-with-bitbucket-cloud-bamboo-aws-codedeploy-2228f9e8d3d3#.ice6yx5pl) post on correcting “XSRF Check failed” errors, I still get the 403 error, not sure what I am doing wrong, has anyone else gone through this problem? 
what was done to finally fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: What code are you referring to? the server.xml file?

Comment: ' <Connector
            port="8443"

            maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            disableUploadTimeout="true"
            acceptCount="100"

            enableLookups="false"
            maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"

            useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"

            scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
            clientAuth="false"
        />
'